# Android Activity windowBackground transparent gradient

Tags: android, background, styles, gradient

I'm asked to do an activity with the following background:
[image]

But this is what I'm getting:

[image]

This is my colors.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#ffff</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#2a68c4</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#ffff</color>
    <color name="colorBlueTransparent">#803e4ca7</color>
</resources>
```

This is activity_background.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:endColor="#8000ffff"
        android:startColor="#4590ff" />
</shape>
```

styles.xml :

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/activity_background</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondaryInverse">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:colorForeground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>
    <style name="DefaultFontStyle" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Button">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And I reference the theme in the manifest.
In the Android Studio designer it looks ok (can't run emulator because I have Windows 10...), but testing it on a LG G2 mini, with 4.4.2, and Moto G with 5.1 gives me the image above.
I bet it has something to do with how styles behave in that version, yet I haven't been able to found out what it is.

Comment: you didn't get transparent background on any devices or only on particular device ?

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan I tested on a LG G2 Mini with 4.4.2, getting the result above. I will test on a Moto G with 5.0 in a couple of hours and update. BTW I can't run the emulator because of Windows 10.

Comment: if you get the desired output let me know,